# Looking for advice on improving a custom function in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm estimating last mile delivery costs in an large urban network using by-route distances. I have over 8000 customer agents and over 100 retail store agents plotted in a GIS map using lat/long coordinates. Each customer receives deliveries from its nearest store (by route). The goal is to get two distance measures in this network for each store:

d0_bar: the average distance from a store to all of its assigned customers
d1_bar: the average distance between all customers common to a single store

I've written a startup function with a simple foreach loop to assign each customer to a store based on by-route distance (customers have a parameter, "customer.pStore" of Store type). This function also adds, in turn, each customer to the store agent's collection of customers ("store.colCusts"; it's an array list with Customer type elements).

Next, I have a function that iterates through the store agent population and calculates the two average distance measures above (d0_bar & d1_bar) and writes the results to a txt file (see code below). The code works, fortunately. However, the problem is that with such a massive dataset, the process of iterating through all customers/stores and retrieving distances via the openstreetmap.org API takes **forever**. It's been initializing ("Please wait...") for about 12 hours. What can I do to make this code more efficient? Or, is there a better way in AnyLogic of getting these two distance measures for each store in my network?

Thanks in advance.

```
    //for each store, record all customers assigned to it
    for (Store store : stores) 
        {
        distancesStore.print(store.storeCode + "," + store.colCusts.size() + "," + store.colCusts.size()*(store.colCusts.size()-1)/2 + ",");
    
    //calculates average distance from store j to customer nodes that belong to store j
        double sumFirstDistByStore = 0.0;
        int h = 0;
        while (h < store.colCusts.size())
            {
            sumFirstDistByStore += store.distanceByRoute(store.colCusts.get(h));
            h++;
            }
        distancesStore.print((sumFirstDistByStore/store.colCusts.size())/1609.34 + ",");
            
    //calculates average of distances between all customer nodes belonging to store j
        double custDistSumPerStore = 0.0;
        int loopLimit = store.colCusts.size();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < loopLimit - 1)
            {
            int j = 1;
            while (j < loopLimit)
                {
                custDistSumPerStore += store.colCusts.get(i).distanceByRoute(store.colCusts.get(j));
                j++;
                }
            i++;
            }   
        distancesStore.print((custDistSumPerStore/(loopLimit*(loopLimit-1)/2))/1609.34);
        distancesStore.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly a few simple comments:

1. Have you tried timing a single `distanceByRoute` call? E.g. can you try running `store.distanceByRoute(store.colCusts.get(0));` just to see how long a single call takes on your system. Routing is generally pretty slow, but it would be good to know what the *speed limit* is.
2. The first simple change is to use java parallelism. Instead of using this:

```java
    for (Store store : stores)
    { ...
```

use this:

```java
    stores.parallelStream().forEach(store -> {
    ...
    });
```

this will process *stores* entries in parallel using [standard Java streams API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html).

3. It also looks like the second loop - where avg distance between customers is calculated doesn't take account of mirroring. That is to say distance a->b is equal to b->a. Hence, for example, 4 customers will require 6 calculations: 1->2, 1->3, 1->4, 2->3, 2->4, 3->4. Whereas in case of 4 customers your second `while` loop will perform 9 calculations: i=0, j in {1,2,3}; i=1, j in {1,2,3}; i=2, j in {1,2,3}, which seems wrong unless I am misunderstanding your intention.
4. Generally, for long running operations it is a good idea to include some `traceln` to show progress with associated timing.

Please have a look at above and post results. With more information additional performance improvements may be possible.

Comment: Thanks. 1) I wrote and tested the code with only a sliver of the data (2 stores, 16 customers). When I ran the model then, the time to initialize was almost unnoticeable (probably less than a second, but I didn't check the console for it). 2) This is interesting. I'll look into this more. 3) You're right, there's a mistake. Should be int j = i+1. I'm assuming an undirected network, so a->b should be the same as b->a. 4) Good advice. Thanks.

Comment: One more things to add: a speed up might be achieved by adding more memory to the JVM (will reduce GC pauses)

Comment: Following up, how does parallelStream() differ from setting the number of processors to use under runtime preferences? Also, the store agents in my model aren't a collection, they're a population. Looks like parallelStream() has to be done on a collection; am I understanding that right?

Comment: parallelSteams() is a Java functionality, number of processors to use refers to multi run experiments only. yes, `parallelStreams()` are only applicable to collection but there is nothing stopping you from putting Store agents into a collection, they can be reference from more than one place (i.e. population and collection).